# Поднятие метода

Tags: методы, ооп, c++

Привет, пытаюсь сделать поднятие метода в c++. Получаю ошибку линкови метода create.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class A
{};

class AChild1:public A
{};

class AChild2:public A
{};

class Base
{
public:

    virtual A* create()=0;

    Base()
    {
        a = create();
    }
public:
    A* a;
};

class BaseChild1:Base
{
public:
    A* create()
    {
        return new AChild1();
    }

};

class BaseChild2:Base
{
public:
    A* create()
    {
        return new AChild2();
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    BaseChild1* b1 = new BaseChild1();
    BaseChild2* b2 = new BaseChild2();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще использование виртуальных функций в конструкторах и деструкторах очень плохая идея. Еще нужно внимательно следить, чтобы в конструкторах и деструкторах не было вызова методов внутри которых, производится вызов вирутальных методов. В таком случае можно не получить ошибок компилятора, а потом долго искать из-за чего программа падает или ведет себя не так как планировалось. Опять же если методы не чисто виртуальные, то ошибки при компиляции не будет.

В момент вызова деструктора или конструктора класс вы работате непосредственно с с этим классом, т.е.
class Child: public Base

конструктор Child вызывает конструктор Base, но в конструкторе Base ничего не известно об Child, соответственно если будут вызываться виртуальные методы, то их реализация будет искать среди методов Base и его базовых классов, аналогично с деструктором.

Comment: Это очень правильно, но как это отвечает на вопрос?

Comment: @VladD а где вопрос? Человек подробно описал в чём проблема и почему возникает ошибка при линковке. Что ещё нужно ответить?

Comment: @Andrey Buran: ошибка линковки происходит не из-за использования виртуальных функций в конструкторе. Ошибка происходит потому, что отсутствует реализация задекларированного метода. То, вызывается этот метод или нет, к ошибкам линковки никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: @VladD а теперь ещё раз внимательно прочитайте ответ @hokum2004

Comment: @Andrey Buran: Перечитал, ничего не поменялось. Может быть, вы укажете, где там говорится об отсутствующей реализации функции? Я увидел лишь рассуждения об _использовании_ виртуальных функций. (Виртуальность функции к ошибкам линковки никакого отношения не имеет.)

Comment: @Vladd "если будут вызываться виртуальные методы, то их реализация будет искать среди методов Base и его базовых классов, аналогично с деструктором." Рассуждение о поиске реализации виртуального метода, которой нет. Если для вас это не очевидно, то мне жаль. Признайтесь, вы придираетесь на пустом месте.

Answer (score 1):

Компилятор говорит

> prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2a): undefined reference to `Base::create()'

В переводе это значит что он не может найти реализацию этого метода. Видимо её нет.
Вы пытаетесь вызвать метод, который чуть выше объявлен нулевым. И, как уже посоветовали, стоит ознакомиться с особенностью поведения виртуальных методов в конструкторе.

Answer (score 0):

Вызов виртуального метода в конструкторе Base - очень плохая идея.